# ggplot2 geom_qq change theoretical data

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, stat, p-value

I have a set of `pvalues` i.e `0<=pval<=1`
I want to plot qqplot using `ggplot2`
As in the [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_qq.html) the following code will plot a q_q plot, however if my data are pvalues **I want the therotical values to be also probabilites** ie. `0<=therotical v<=1`

```
df <- data.frame(y = rt(200, df = 5))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(sample = y))
p + stat_qq() + stat_qq_line()
```

I am aware of the  `qqplot.pvalues` from [gaston](https://rdrr.io/cran/gaston/man/qqplot.pvalues.html) package it does the job but the plot is not as customizable as the ggplot version.
In `gaston` package the theoretical data are plotted as `-log10((n:1)/(n + 1))` where n is number of pvalues. How to pass these values to ggplot as theoritical data?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some p-values, say from a normal distribution you could create it manually

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(outcome = rnorm(150))
data$pval <- pnorm(data$outcome)
data <- data[order(data$pval),]

ggplot(data = data, aes(y = pval, x = pnorm(qnorm(ppoints(nrow(data)))))) +
         geom_point() +
         geom_abline(slope = 1) + 
         labs(x = 'theoraetical p-val', y = 'observed p-val', title = 'qqplot (pval-scale)')
```

Although I am not sure this plot is sensible to use for conclusions.